# How do I make vim display virtual space at the bottom when opening a file?

Tags: vimrc, scrolling

I really like not having my cursor at the bottom part of the screen. Using `:set scrolloff=20` does help when scrolling down a file, but it doesn't work when I reach the bottom (unless I `zz`).

Another problem (and the main question) is how to get vim to show the virtual space when opening a file? I have it setup to set the cursor at the last line where I was editing, and if that line is at the end of the file, it will open at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
au BufWinEnter * exe "normal zz"
```

But I guess there will be side effects. Test thoroughly.

One side effect: Assume you have 2 buffers loaded and Vim has only one ("full terminal") window. So one buffer is displayed. The other is hidden. If you switch to the hidden buffer, `zz` will be executed.

Comment: I feel kinda dumb now that I see this hehe. Thanks though! Any thoughts on possible side effects? So far I haven't run into any.

Comment: @JakubArnold See update